# The Module DLL C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\apnetcorev2.dll failed to load. The data is the error

Tags: iis-10, asp.net-core-6.0

I have recently update an aspnetcore project from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET 6.0.

Since the update, the application will not run in IIS 10.0.
When I attempt to run the application, the application pool exits, and I see the following error in the Event Viewer:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP
Date:          1/18/2023 10:37:14 AM
Event ID:      2280
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      MACHINENAME.dev.oati.local
Description:
The Module DLL C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\apnetcorev2.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP" Guid="{670080D9-742A-4187-8D16-41143D1290BD}" EventSourceName="W3SVC-WP" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">2280</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-01-18T16:37:14.436510400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>368815</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>MACHINENAME.dev.oati.local</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="ModuleDll">C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\apnetcorev2.dll</Data>
    <Binary>7E000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I have installed the relevant Windows Hosting Bundle:

[image]

I have installed the relevant Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable:

[image]

I'm not sure what to check next. I have gone through multiple similar stackoverflow questions, as well as the aspnetcore github issues list and have not gotten a good idea of what to look at next to debug the issue.

**EDIT**:

Here is the Jexus Manager output for the application --

[image]

So it says ASP.NET Core module version 2 is not installed properly.
It is not clear to me why that would be the case, or how to remedy it.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report and include it in the question body. That should reveal more information on your setup.

Comment: I tried migrating from .net2 to .net6 and deploying it on IIS, it works. The difference between me and your picture is that I have installed `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable(x86) -14.34.31931` more than you.

Comment: That is the same redistributable, except that x86 version (I have the x64 version). Is there a reason I would need the x86 version on a 64-bit OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever set up the module somehow introduced a typo.

Changing

C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\apnetcorev2.dll

to

C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll

Fixes the error.